# How to mock Azure Queue storage for unit test?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, xunit

I want to mock  QueueMessage for unit test,but I can not find any lib to mock

```
    public  async Task<QueueMessage[]> ReceiveMessagesAsync(QueueClient queue)
       {
     
        QueueProperties properties = queue.GetProperties();

        // Retrieve the cached approximate message count.
        int cachedMessagesCount = properties.ApproximateMessagesCount;
        QueueMessage[] queueMessages =new QueueMessage[cachedMessagesCount];

        int num = cachedMessagesCount / 32;

        for (int i = 0; i < num + 1; i++)
        {
         var  messages = await queue.ReceiveMessagesAsync(maxMessages: 32);
         messages.Value.CopyTo(queueMessages,i*32);
        }
        return queueMessages;
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of mocking aspects of an _EAI System_?  A message is just the envelope.  You want the payload.  Wouldn't it instead be better to test the handler for the payload.  A [well-written system](https://www.amazon.com.au/Soa-Design-Patterns-Thomas-Erl/dp/0136135161) should have its business logic **de-coupled** from any EAI system

Comment: @MickyD thank you for your comment! You really got a point there and I solved this unneeded issue by just returning QueueMessage.MessageText instead of the object itself. Absolutely true point which needs to be considered!

Answer (score 5):

The constructors of the Queue models are internal, but you can create objects using the [QueuesModelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.models.queuesmodelfactory?view=azure-dotnet) which provides utilities for mocking.

```
QueueMessage queueMsg = QueuesModelFactory.QueueMessage(
    messageId: "id2", 
    popReceipt: "pr2", 
    body: JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Test"), 
    dequeueCount: 1, 
    insertedOn: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);

 var metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value" }, };
 int messageCount = 5;
 QueueProperties queueProp = QueuesModelFactory.QueueProperties(metadata, messageCount);
```

Answer (score 3):

Choice of Mocking lib would be an opinionated answer. There are several mocking frameworks available. One of the popular ones is [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4).

Using Moq, the sample test for your above code would look like below. Note that mocking storage lib is a bit tedious task as you can see.

```
        [Test]
        public async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
        {
            // Arrange
            var queueClientHelper = new QueueClientHelper();
            var queueMock = new Mock<QueueClient>();
            var mockPropertiesResponse = new Mock<Response<QueueProperties>>();
            var properties = new QueueProperties();
            properties.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(properties.ApproximateMessagesCount), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(properties, 64); // little hack since ApproximateMessagesCount has internal setter
            mockPropertiesResponse.SetupGet(r => r.Value).Returns(properties);
            queueMock.Setup(q => q.GetProperties(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(mockPropertiesResponse.Object);
            var mockMessageReponse = new Mock<Response<QueueMessage[]>>();
            mockMessageReponse.SetupGet(m => m.Value).Returns(new QueueMessage[32]);
            queueMock.Setup(q => q.ReceiveMessagesAsync(It.IsAny<int?>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan?>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(mockMessageReponse.Object);

            // Act
            var result = await queueClientHelper.ReceiveMessagesAsync(queueMock.Object);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(64, result.Length);
            // verify mocks as required
        }
```

Comment: Thank u so much!Ghosh

Answer (score 1):

Try to mock the response of queueClient this will verify sendMessageAsync response

```
[Fact]
    public async Task SendMessage_ShouldReturnSuccess()
    {
        var receipt = QueuesModelFactory.SendReceipt("1", DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(2), "pop", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1));
        var res = Response.FromValue<SendReceipt>(receipt, null);
        var queueClientmock = new Mock<QueueClient>();
        queueClientmock.Setup(q => q.SendMessageAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(res));
        var sqmock = new Mock<IStorageQueueProvider>();
        sqmock.Setup(s => s.GetStorageQueueClient()).Returns(Task.FromResult(queueClientmock.Object)).Verifiable();
        var storageQueueRepository = new StorageQueueRepository(sqmock.Object, DummyLogger);
        var result = await storageQueueRepository.SendMessage("test message");
        result.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        return QueuesModelFactory.QueueMessage(
            messageId: "id2",
            popReceipt: "pr2",
            body: BinaryData.FromString(encode ? Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Message)) : Message),
            dequeueCount: dequeueCount,
            insertedOn: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).